# How do I test if a block is anything but a certain block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to test for a player standing on anything apart from ice.

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:ice 0
```

Comment: Invert the output from the command you've given?

Comment: I beleive the use of an exclamation mark would be useful perhaps? `!` Generally signifies the opposite of the intended outcome, so perhaps try `!minecraft:ice 0`

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ -1 ~ minecraft:ice
```

then link it with a comparator to a block with a redstone torch on the opposite side, then connect that to the command block saying what you want it to do.

Comment: But if he isn't standing on ice the command block won't give an output to switch the torch. So it would be the same as if there was't a torch to invert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scoreboard objective to "invert" the command for multiple players and without needing a comparator

Create the objective using

```
scoreboard objectives add onIce dummy
```

Now, create a fill/setblock clock (do not use another clock!), and run the following two commands in order:

```
scoreboard players set @a onIce 0
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:ice scoreboard players set @p onInce 1
```

Now, you can use the target selector argument `score_onIce=0` to select only players not on ice, or `score_onIce_min=1` for the opposite. For example,

```
testfor @a[score_onIce=0]
```

will check if there are any players that are not currently on ice.